# Why does this Objective-c delegate method work even when I implement it as a class method?

Tags: objective-c, oop, singleton

I have a class that only contains class methods, and returns an instantiated MKMapView object.

I also wanted to handle the map location event, so I implemented  with the `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` method.

The code looks something like this:

```
+ (UIView *)create{
    MKMapView *mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
    [mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    mapView.delegate = [self self];
    return mapView;
}
+ (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation{
    NSLog(@"Location changed! :%@", userLocation);
}
```

While I was doing this I became puzzled how this actually works. If you look closely, since this class is not meant to be instantiated, all the methods are class methods, and this includes even the `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` method.

I thought this was strange since the `MKMapView` only declares the instance method version and no class method. And yet, this code works just fine.

**So my question is: How does this work? And is it OK to write code this way?**

p.s.
I could create a singleton instead, but I did it this way because I didn't want to write the extra singleton init code for every new class like this (This class is sort of like a plugin and I want to minimize the amount of custom code that needs to be written).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the nature of Objective-C: a class *is* an object. It's actually an instance, too: of its metaclass. Methods are called on a class object in the same way they're called on other instances: a message is passed to the object, and it looks up the selector. Nothing changes if the object is a class instead of an instance of a class. Simply, but perhaps confusingly at first, *class methods *are instance methods* on the class object*.

Further, in Cocoa, the `NSObject` metaclass implements the `NSObject` protocol, so all class objects have basic functionality like `respondsToSelector:`. Since that's how a delegating object tests whether it can send a certain message to its delegate, your class object can participate in a delegate relationship without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it's working because you are passing the class as a delegate instance. As classes are considering objects this (technically) will work. Apple's code that calls the delegate method will be doing something like checking to see if the delegate responds to the relevant selector (selects don't differentiate between class and instance) and simply calling it. Therefore your class declaration of the method works.

However I would recommend that you change to using instances correctly. What you have done may work, but it's not how the API was expected to work. Further it's vulnerable to Apple changing the way that the delegate methods are called. If they change the code so it only works with actual instances, your code will stop working.

Comment: There's no need for the caution here. This is how ObjC works: classes _are_ instances, and you send messages to them just like other objects. I'm not even sure _how_ Apple could "change the code so it only works with actual instances" if they wanted to.

Comment: Apple could check if the delegate instance is an instance of type `Class`.  That just leaves the question of _why_ they'd do that...

Comment: They might ad code to validate the method exists as an instance method under the reasonable assumption that it will be defined as such. Then the method would not be called. I've actually never seen anyone use a class as a delegate before like this.